# Having trouble in filter array of dictionaries coming from server in swift

Tags: ios, swift

The dictionary coming from server is

```
{
    data = ({
        email = "a123@gmail.com";
        phone = 9804504884;
        "user_id" = 11;
        username = abcd;
    });
}

var dataArray:NSArray = dict.objectForKey("data") as! NSArray
println("names = ,\(dataArray)");
var pre:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "username CONTAINS[c] a")
var result:NSArray = dataArray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(pre)
println("names = ,\(result)");
```

I am always getting result blank result array from this swift code.
 Please help me to resolve this issue.
 Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this,

```
let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username CONTAINS[C] 'a'")
if let filteredArray = json["data"]?.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate) {
   // do something with array
}
```

Note you should wrap your string inside single quotes *''*.